# Christian origins reference request

Tags: hebrew

Can anyone provide a source that says to the effect that Christianity and Judaism originate from a religion that existed in Israel in the 1st millennium BC that called their God something that in English might have sounded like Yahweh?

Comment: This question would, IMHO, be more relevant to the https://christianity.stackexchange.com site than here.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Answer (score 1):

Although this would be better dealt with in the Christianity site, I will answer it, in the hope that a Moderator will transfer it.

The best source for tracing Christianity back to pre-Christian Judaism is the Bible. It refers to The Divine Name for the Creator, the one God whom the ancient forebears of the nation of Israel came to know as YHWH. This is in the first book of the Hebrew scriptures, Genesis, and crops up 6,961 times in Hebrew (which includes 134 times where the Masoretic text shows that ancient copyists called Sopherim had changed the primitive Hebrew text to read *Adho.nay* or *Elo.him* instead of *Yehowah*). The question asks about the religion in Israel, during the 1st millennium B.C., that might have used that name (which, in the English language can be pronounced as Yahweh.) This is where Jewish scholars have something to say about what they call Hashem, "The Name".

***In Hebrew, the name of God is spelled:***
יהוה   In English, that transliterates as YHWH. Hebrew doesn't have any true vowels. Most words are spelled with only consonants. Because taking The Name in vain breaks one of the 10 commandments and was considered blasphemy, The Name was rarely pronounced in Israel.

In modern Hebrew, YHWH can be pronounced "Yahweh." The English transliteration of YHWH is "Jehovah," which we get via Latin. Many scholars say 'Yahweh' is better than 'Jehovah'.

However, there is another name, very similar, **the name ‘Yahveh’, but that is NOT a pronunciation of YHWH**. That's because, according to the Talmud, Yahveh is the name of the Archangel Metatron, who because of his extreme Godliness, was given a new name by God that was almost the same as God's:
יהבה    Those letters are transliterated as YHVH into English and the name is pronounced "Yahveh" in Hebrew.

It must be pointed out that Talmudic traditions like that are not in the Bible.

The letter ו in Hebrew, the third letter in the name יהוה (YHWH) since Hebrew reads from right to left instead of from left to right, is the letter vav. Like many English letters, many Hebrew letters have more than one pronunciation. The letter vav is one of those letters and is pronounced either as a V or as a W, but in a few words, it is used to indicate the vowels O or U. Hebrew generally doesn't use vowels, but when it occasionally does, it's a consonant that is being used as a vowel. In YHWH, the vav is always pronounced as a W: "YahWeh." It cannot be construed as being pronounced as a V because of the name YHVH or "YahVeh" whose third letter is ב or bet. While the letter bet can be pronounced as either a V or a B in Hebrew, it is only ever pronounced as a B when there is a dot in the middle of it: בּ. Without that dot, it's always pronounced as a V.

Since YHVH in the Talmud is stated as being very much like, but still different from, **YHWH, the actual name of God, the vav in YHWH is always pronounced as a W and not a V** or else the two names would be pronounced exactly the same and thus contradict the Talmud's teachings.

Some of this information comes from a book and two booklets dealing with The Divine Name, none having copyright. They were released for worldwide internet distribution in 2001 (eleven in all) and should be freely available at http://www.tetragrammaton.org  The author died some years ago but never gave his name in his publications, but years of study resulted in meticulous examination of manuscripts of the Bible to explain the significance of The Divine Name.